# How to seperate SQL query result based on parts of the column input

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I'm wondering if it is even possible and how to do this. We work with SQL Server 2005

Someone asked me a question to sum up the volume used on the storage per day.
The size of files is stored in our DB as pixelsize. in the same table also the datetime column is available. It contains records like this: 2009-01-31 10:59:13.000

So to get the total size stored per day I need to count the pixelsize records and then seperate them by date so that the end result is that i get the volume pixel size per day.

Till now I  got this:

```html
select round (sum(pixeldatafilesize)/1048576,2) as studysizemb
from filename
where DateTime between '2014-05-01' and '2014-06-01'
```

I tried to add `group by datetime asc` but it fails to give me the correct result.

Does anyone know how to separate correctly in this case?

Comment: Try this query - `SELECT CAST(DateColumn AS DATE), ROUND(SUM(pixeldatafilesize) / 1048576, 2) AS studysizemb
FROM [filename]
WHERE CAST(DateColumn AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014-05-01'
  AND '2014-06-01'
GROUP BY CAST(DateColumn AS DATE)`

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying so quickly.
this query provides me with a record for each unique milisecond.
would be great if it could be the size in mb per day.

Comment: Could you post or show us the the expected output ??

Comment: As the query filter between 05-01 and 06-01 (f.ex) expectation is that result gives back 30 (each day of the month) containing numbers (indicates amount of MB used)
So the above i started with provides only 1 record containing the mb used on the hole month of may while i did like to see it seperately by day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've dealt with this in the past I've used something like

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(pixeldatafilesize)/1048576,2) AS studysizemb,CONVERT(varchar(50),DateTime ,101)  AS DateTime FROM filename 
WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-06-01' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(50),DateTime ,101)
```

Which should give you dates formatted as 09/17/2014 and will return the same value for any time of day.

Comment: Thanks, That helped a bit. was able to get it in a good format using the convert and charchar